# Case statement to control the different output

Tags: sql

I have a query like this

```
Select SSN, FName, MName, LName, sum(WagesAmt) as WagesAmt, sum(OtherAmt) as OtherAmt
      from #data
      group by SSN, FName, MName, LName
      having sum(WagesAmt) <> 0
```

When it come to the other State, I want the output to combine the Lastname, Fname, Mname.

Do I need do something like these:

```
declare @result table

set @result = case 
when  then select 
when  then select
```

My question is how can I write a case statement to control the different output requirements?

For TX
the output will like

ssn   FNAME, LName, amount
1111   jon    WANG   3444

for CA

the output will be something like these

1111  WANG, J   34444

sorry for the confuse
thanks

Comment: Try to express your requirements using an example input dataset and the results that you desire.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a little time to read the [FAQ] before long.  Beware of people (like me) who don't have a middle name.  If the Mname column contains NULL, then an expression like `Fname || ' ' || Mname || ' ' || Lname` produces a null string (at least in Standard SQL) because one term is NULL.  However, that aside, your question is not at all clear.  You mention 'other State' but it is not clear that there's any State in the current query.  Are you looking to vary the condition, or the returned columns?  Can you show some simple input data and output data?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine State is the condition that will tell you if you want your fName and Lname as different columns or same column, right?

The thing is, as long as you have all the fields you use on your select on your group by, its fine. The secret on your case is that you will need an empty column when you have Fname and Lname togheter, a column with a CASE and the second column with an oposite CASE

I hope this simple example can help you:

```
CREATE table names(
firstName varchar(50),
lastName varchar(50),
condition int,
amount int)

insert into names VALUES('First1', 'Last1', 1, 10)
insert into names VALUES('First1', 'Last1', 1, 10)
insert into names VALUES('First2', 'Last2', 2, 5)
insert into names VALUES('First2', 'Last2', 2, 5)


SELECT 
case 
    when condition=1 then firstname
    else firstname + ' - ' + lastname
    END,
case
    when condition=1 then lastname
    else ''
    END,
sum(amount)
FROM names
group BY firstname, lastname, condition
```

result:

```
Column1                     Column2          Column3
First1                        Last1               20
First2 - Last2                                    10
```